# Javascript Scroll to section

Tags: javascript

I want to scroll to a section on the page with vanilla JavaScript. Is the browser support good?

This is my code:

```
Document.getElementById("menu-item-1").on("click", function() { 
  Document.getElementById("services").scrollIntoView();
};
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a id="menu-item-1" href="#services">Click to Scroll to Services</a>
```

Then add services id where you want to scroll to.

```html
<div id="services">Scroll Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried linking an id?

```html
<h1 id="menu-item-1">Menu Item #1</h1>
<div>Go to <a href="#menu-item-1">Menu Item #1</a></div>
```

(The code above doesn't scroll because it is inside of a sandbox)

Comment: Add `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` in CSS to add smooth scrolling with anchors. Works on [most modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior), except Safari.