# HTML button click redirect to a <div> tab on the same page

Tags: html

I have this code:

```js
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
   var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
   tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
   for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
       tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
   }

   tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
   for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
       tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
   }

   document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
   elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Settings', this, 'orange')">Settings</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>About:</h3>
    <input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="history.go(0)" />
</div>
```

This display on the same page a tab called `About` and `Settings` tab, in `About` tab I have a `Refresh` button.

I want this tab to redirect me to the `Settings` tab of the same html file. how can I do this ?

- I have tried using the `<a>` to wrap the whole `<div>` but it didnt do anything.
- All redirect docs talk about redirecting to a link but i didnt find anything on redirecting to the same page to a different `<div>` tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Scroll to section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132368/javascript-scroll-to-section)

Comment: Can your replace this <input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="openPage('Settings', this, 'orange')" />\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replaced onClick event in refresh button. Hope this help you.

```js
if (location.hash != '') {
  openPage('Settings', this, 'orange');
}

function refresh() {
  if (history.pushState) {
    var url = (location.href).replace("#setting", '');
    history.pushState(null, null, url + '#setting');
    location.reload();
  }
}

function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Settings', this, 'orange')">Settings</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About:</h3>
  <input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="refresh()" />
</div>
```

Comment: This does work! thank you but it doesnt applay the refresh of the data ( i see same data and after real refresh F5 i see real data) how can i fix ?

Answer (score 0):

use bookmarking

ex:

```
 <a href="#your_Id">something</a>
  <div id="my-id">anything</div>
```